# Analytic function with zero derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that if $f$ analytic at $z_0$ and $f(z_0)=f'(z_0)=\dots=f^{(m)}(z_0)=0$, then the function $g$ defined by means of the equations $$g(z) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{m+1}}, & \text{if }z\neq z_0 \\
\dfrac{f^{(m+1)}(z_0)}{(m+1)!}, & \text{if } z=z_0
\end{cases}$$ is analytic at $z_0$.

My approach was the following. Since $f$ is analytic at $z_0$ then it is analytic in some nbhd of $z_0$ then by Taylor's theorem $f(z)=\sum \limits_{k=m+1}^{\infty} \dfrac{f^{(k)}(z_0)}{k!}(z-z_0)^k$. How to show that $g(z)$ is analytic at $z_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U$ be the domain of $f$. Take $z_1\in U$. You want to prove that, for same $r>0$ such that $D(z_1,r)\subset U$, there is a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_1)^n$ whose sum, in $D(z_1,r)$, is $g(z)$. There are two possibilities:

- $z_1\ne z_0$: then $z_1\in U\setminus\{z_0\}$ and, on $U\setminus\{z_0\}$, $g$ is the quotien of two analytic functions and therefore it is analytic there. So, by the definition of analytic function, it can be written on some disk $D(z_1,r)$ as the sum of a power series centered at $z_1$.
- $z_1=z_0$: you have, on some disk $D(z_0,r)$,\begin{align}g(z)&=\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{m+1}}\\&=\frac{\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty\frac{f^{(k)}(z_0)}{k!}(z-z_0)^k}{(z-z_0)^{m+1}}\\&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(m+1+k)}(z_0)}{(m+1+k)!}(z-z_0)^k.\end{align}

Comment: The phrase "near points other than $z_0$" and "near $z_0$" confuses me a lot. I guess you need clarify them

Comment: Cab you clarify your answer please?

Comment: Done. Is it clear now?